# Admob: Monetizing, what do orange countries mean

Tags: admob

When i check the Monetize app, select clicks and then let the data present in the world map I see several countries that have a light orange color. When I hover over them it tells me that there where no clicks in this country.
Is this intentional? Does it mean that those are removed misclicks or is it just random?

I'm thinking its because in those countries other data informations are available (like impressions) but I can't find a place to confirm it.

Answer (score 1):

Statistics admob this magical thing. But usually, if you look at the statistics for the past month, it is not. As you know, the data on clicks all the time updated and checked. Therefore, there may be these "artifacts". Never mind.
[But of course you can send them a report.](https://support.google.com/admob/?ctx=ui&hl=en)